# Issue with apt-get update, Jessie repeats

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, apt, update

Newbie to the Pi so this may be a dumb question.

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3

In following the suggestions to use "sudo apt-get update" the update system seems to be stuck.  I keep getting updates for Jessie which seem to repeat forever.  I have tried restarts and the system seems to think the patches haven't been applied.

Is this something I can address or do I need to wait for the Jessie maintainers to fix something?

Here is an example Terminal Session, my entries are **Bold**:

**pi@rasp-pi-01:~ $ sudo apt-get update**

Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease

Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease

Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages

Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages

Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages

Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/staging armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/staging Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/staging Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en

Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en_GB

Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en

Reading package lists... Done

**pi@rasp-pi-01:~ $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Calculating upgrade... Done

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
pi@rasp-pi-01:~ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of dist-upgrade (which would upgrade your distro e.g. wheezy to jessie) try sudo apt-get upgrade (after update)

Basic functionality for apt-get

update: fetch up packages versions on repositories you have

upgrade: compare updated versions with current installed ones and upgrade'en

dist-upgrade: compare distro version and upgrade it

Comment: Huczu awnser is correct, I guess. Your question kind of leaves it open for interpretation.

Comment: Ah, update vs upgrade.  interesting.

Comment: Yup, kinda confusing when coming from windows, had the same doubt first time using linux. It makes a lot of sense though

Comment: Yep, I am from Windows and having command lines make sense is a novel experience!

Answer (score 3):

To explain what `sudo apt-get update` is doing please read: [What does “sudo apt-get update” do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do)

To update your system you should use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` after doing an update of repository.

If it stuck please edit your post and paste logs from update command.

@edit:

After edit I see everything is OK. Your repository has been updated to actual without errors. Next you tried upgrade your dist and `apt-get` tells you everything is up to date.